# How to let JavaScript function continue even after server shuts down?

Tags: javascript, tomcat, grails, application-shutdown

I am writing a Grails application to Restart the application server.

On clicking the link, I call a javascript function which would reload & redirect after 15 secs. And in the controller-action of the link I call a unix script in which I do tomcat shutdown & startup.

The js functions starts but is shutdown with the server. 
Is there anyway in which the user gets to see the reload/wait page while the restart is happeneing at the background. P

Answer (score 1):

In the reload/wait page, have a JavaScript function making an AJAX request to the server ever N seconds, until the request finally succeeds, indicating that the server has been restarted. Then redirect to some page served by the server.

Comment: He can only make ajax request and show status without redirection to new page. When redirect will occur server can be in reload state.